# Will Google reCaptcha work once Chrome blocks usage of third party cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, recaptcha, third-party-cookies

The both versions(V2,V3) of google recaptcha sets third party cookies . As you might know Chrome will block the usage of third party cookies in 2024. Will recaptcha work then or implementation on user side has to be changed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the cookies set by recaptcha have the [`Partitioned`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies) attribute, they should still work even in a third-party context. Is that the case?

Comment: The cookie does not have Partitioned at the moment, at least on our website. I am also wondering what will happen in 2024 with recaptcha!

Comment: @Darep, you can test it in advance with chrome://flags/#test-third-party-cookie-phaseout

Comment: Cheers! Tested it and recaptcha seemed to work, though it does want me to click the captcha images every single time I open the page anew, hehe :) No cookie appears at any point.

Comment: reCAPTCHA v3 seems to work as well with this flag enabled. It still sets a Cookie from the Google Domain (identified with the name NID).

Comment: Same for me, it works when the cookies are blocked, but I'd rather it didn't try and set them. I don't understand why Google would phase out third-party cookies within their browser, then have other products that do not adhere to their own policies?